# Storage differences between OS X and iOS

Tags: ios, macos, storage

I'm writing some binary data files on OS X to read on iOS devices.  I was trying to read and write the following structure:

```
struct poiStruct {
    double latitude, longitude;
    char titleString[41];
};
```

I find using sizeof that the structure occupies 64 bytes on OS X and 60 bytes on iOS.

Any ideas/explanations on this are much appreciated!

Comment: I have an idea but not actual explanation. However, I have a *solution*: `__attribute__((packed))`...

Answer (score 7):

Difference is not in size of elements but in padding, on OSX the struct gets aligned to 8 bytes boundary so it's

```
XXXXXXXX double (8 bytes)
YYYYYYYY double (8 bytes)
ZZZZZZZZ char (41 bytes)
ZZZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZZZ
ZPPPPPPP padding (7 bytes) = 64 bytes
```

while on iOS it's aligned to 4 bytes so it's

```
XXXX double (8 bytes)
XXXX 
YYYY double (8 bytes)
YYYY
ZZZZ char (41 bytes)
ZZZZ
ZZZZ
ZZZZ
ZZZZ
ZZZZ
ZZZZ
ZZZZ
ZZZZ
ZZZZ
ZPPP padding (3 bytes) = 60 bytes
```

The alignment is a requirement which is different because OS X runs on a 64 architecture while iOS runs on ARM6/7 is a 32 bytes architecture. Compiling your OS X application in 32bit mode (which is possible but I discourage it) should make this difference disappear.

Comment: Jack - thanks for the explanation ... it makes perfect sense!  I'm flexible right now so I can update the data structure to fall on the same alignment for both architectures.

Answer (score 2):

Your Mac App is a 64bit App while the iOS version is 32bit. The difference comes from different padding requirements of the architectures, specifically 32bit requires variables to be 4byte aligned while 64bit requires 8byte alignment, so the compiler will add a different amount of padding at the end of your structure.

Comment: Specifically? Even I could provide an answer like this :)

Comment: @H2CO3 32bit requires 4byte alignment while 64bit requires 8byte alignment. That's why both architectures require a different amount of padding at the end of the structure.

Comment: Thanks JustSid - your help is much appreciated!  I'm going to adjust the data structure to align on a common boundary for both platforms.